# How to restart neo4j ha cluster and update the graph.db data?

Tags: neo4j

I have a neo4j ha cluster with one master and two slave. 
We will periodically regenerate the neo4j data offline, then push it to the master, restart the cluster, and want the new data synced to the slave.
Now, we do it in these steps.

1. Remove all the 'data/coordinator/version-2' direcotry and execute 'bin/neo4j-coordinator stop' on all neo4j instances, to stop the synchronization.
2. Stop the master instance, remove 'data/graph.db/*' of it, and copy the new data generated offline to the master
3. Execute 'bin/neo4j-coordinator start' on all neo4j instances, to restart the synchronization.
4. Start the master instance with new data. But strangely, the slave instances won't sync the new data until we do the next steps.
5. Stop slave1, remove 'data/graph.db/*' of it and restart it.
6. Stop slave2, remove 'data/graph.db/*' of it and restart it.

I do not quite understand the synchronization mechanism of neo4j, I want to know if there is  a better way to do this, or how can I improve my steps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an offline copy of the data and you can afford to stop all 3 instances at the same time, just copy the offline data to all 3 instances first instead of just the master. Then you know they are all in sync when you start the coordinator and the DBs. Also, I would stop the services first before removing any coordinator data.